# Powerbi: How to calculate average value per hour from value in minutes?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I am building a report that shows the time spent on a job and the income the job has generated. My boss wants to see the average income of a job in hours.

Let's say three jobs have been completed:
Job A: Time: 12 minutes & income 450 euro
Job B: Time: 24 minutes & income 600 euro
Job C: Time: 38 minutes & income 950 euro
Job D: Time: 82 minutes & income 1800 euro

How do i calculate the average income per hour in PowerBI/DAX?

Comment: In what part of it are you having difficulties? You can simply sum the column imcome and divide by the sum of column time. Since you want it in hours, multiply the result by 60 (60 minutes).

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, the DAX would then be: sum((income)/sum(time))*60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in a structured way:

```
DEFINE
    TABLE Payroll = SELECTCOLUMNS ({
    ("Job-A",FORMAT(TIME(00,12,00),"HH:MM:SS"),450),
    ("Job-B",FORMAT(TIME(00,24,00),"HH:MM:SS"),600),
    ("Job-C",FORMAT(TIME(00,38,00),"HH:MM:SS"),950),
    ("Job-D",FORMAT(TIME(00,82,00),"HH:MM:SS"),1800)
    },"Type",[Value1],"Duration",[Value2],"Income",[Value3])
EVALUATE
Payroll
```

[image: KK]

Final Code:

```
    EVALUATE
ROW (
    "AVG_Earnings",
        FORMAT (
            ROUND (
                AVERAGEX (
                    ADDCOLUMNS (
                        ADDCOLUMNS (
                            Payroll,
                            "Hour", HOUR ( Payroll[Duration] ),
                            "Minute", MINUTE ( Payroll[Duration] ),
                            "Seconds", SECOND ( Payroll[Duration] )
                        ),
                        "Total",
                            ROUND ( [Hour] + DIVIDE ( [Minute], 60 ) + DIVIDE ( [Seconds], 3600 ), 4 )
                    ),
                    DIVIDE ( [Income], [Total] )
                ),
                2
            ),
            "Currency",
            "de-DE"
        )
)
```

[image: KK_X]